# Performance Monitor: Counters from ASP.NET v4.0 not available

Tags: asp.net, performance, counter, monitor

We have a Windows Web Server 2008 R2 with .Net 4 installed. When I try to add some of the counters from "ASP.NET v4.0.30319" to the performance monitor, I cannot find that category. It only shows me "ASP.NET v2.0.50727". It is also missing quite a few other categories, like all the ".NET ..." categories.

On another server of ours these categories are visible. How can I make the visible on the first server?

Comment: Have the same issue with a pair of servers. One shows "ASP.NET v4.0.30319" the other not(both show ASP.NET v2). There is no such key on either server as mentioned in the accepted answer. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer on serverfault: https://serverfault.com/questions/25842/performance-monitor-cant-add-counters-from-net-data-providers (second answer - not the one marked as answer).

All I had to do was to delete  the entry “Disable Performance Counters" in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ASP.NET_4.0.30319\Performance. Then I restarted the Performance Monitor and everything was fine. I was able to see the missing category again.

Answer (score 0):

I found the entries to disable (Disable Performance Counters) in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet002\services\ASP.NET_4.0.30319\Performance and for other ASP.NET keys in the registry.